# Efficient ModelChoiceField initial data

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, django-forms

To set initial data for my ModelChoiceFields, currently I do the following:

```
foo = ModelChoiceField(label="Foo label",
                       queryset=Foo.objects.all(),
                       initial=Foo.objects.get(pk=14))
```

But I feel this may be bad practice, & i'm unsure of the most effective way to set initial data. `pk=14` is a record that is the default "N/A".

Currently, as I understand it, both `Foo.objects.all()` & `Foo.objects.get(pk=14)` are making separate queries to the db, does this make for an expensive transaction/ a redundant one? The database for Foo is fairly tiny, but I'm curious how to optimize ModelChoiceField definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing two queries but your code is very clear and easy to read. Unless you have profiled the code and determined that this line is a problem your code is fine.

If you really want to avoid two queries I would suggest looking in the [Django cache](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) and caching the results of the querysets so you can avoid them on subsequent page views.

```
initial = cache.get("foo_modelchoice_initial")
if initial is None:
    initial = Foo.objects.get(pk=14)
    cache.set("foo_modelchoice_initial", initial)

foo = ModelChoiceField(label="Foo label",
                   queryset=Foo.objects.all(),
                   initial=initial)
```

If `Foo.objects.all()` grows very large then this code will become slow, but in that case you'll need to replace with an AJAX lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing two queries, but they are executed at completely different times.

Querysets are lazy. The query in `Foo.objects.all()` is not executed until the form is actually rendered. That means that the list of Foo objects available will always be up-to-date.

However, the `Foo.objects.get(pk=14)` is executed when the form is *defined*, ie the first time its module is imported. So this value persists across requests, as long as the server process remains active. This is good in that the query is not done every time, but potentially bad in that the value will remain even if the object is later deleted from the database.

To answer your specific question then, you are in fact only doing one query each time here.